# Xamarin.Forms using SQLite.Net.Async (the NUGET part)

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, sqlite.net

I'm trying to make a connection to a SQLite database using Visual Studio 2015 the target platform is Android.

I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945223/xamarin-forms-using-sqlite-net-async) but I can not get it to work. My problem is the part of installing packagde.

I want to have my database stuff placed in a Class Library so I've created a new Application, and added a Class Library to the solution.

To install SQLite I've written the following in the packagde manager console:

```
Install-Package SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid -Version 2.3.0
```

But installs SQLLite into my application, not my Class Library.

My Class Library is very very simple:

```
    public class SQLiteDataService
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection connectionFlexCheckDemo;
        private ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform;

        private string FlexCheckDBNameDemo = "FlexCheckDemo.db";

        private void Test()
        {
            var platform = new SQLitePlatformAndroid();            
        }    
    }
```

but it doesn't compile:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'SQLite' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   ...

What am I doing wrong? And more important how to make it work.

Comment: You need to install SQLLite-PCL Async to your class library and the specific platform projects.

Comment: Thankyou @Rohit you need to bee a little more specific because I cant find SQLLite-PCL in Nuget

Comment: I have added an answer with the link to the specific nuget, so that you don't have trouble finding it. :)

Comment: I'll try it out and return shortly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to install the Nuget or the dll to reference the SQLite-Async in your Shared or PCL project so that you can write your common code there like having common CRUD operations or having Unit Of Work coupled with Repository pattern. A simple example can be found [here](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/cross-platform-sqlite-support--part-1).

Then in your platform specific projects you need to have the nuget installed as well, which will get resolved and install the corresponding version based on your platform. I don't think there is a nuget available for WP, so you might have to look for other choices.

This is the nuget package for [SQLite.Net.Async PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/)

Comment: Looks very promising :D

Comment: @JensBorrisholt - Happy to help.